# Positioning and zooming Google map inside RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Part of my application uses RecyclerView with CardView elements, and every CardView element contains Google Map which draws specific route. On every map I am zooming and positioning route inside of map so it can fill whole view but problems arrive when I begin to scroll and every next CardView doesn't position my route inside a map but leaves it unzoomed and unpositioned. Picture is below:

[image: First CardView zoom and position is ok but when scrolled down position of next CardView is not ok]

Im using onBindViewHolder to setup map and route drawing and then I'm using zoomToLatLng to zoom the map

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RouteViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.destination.setText(routesCV.get(position).getDestination());
        holder.startingPoint.setText(routesCV.get(position).getStartingPoint());

        GoogleMap gMap = holder.map.getMap();

        if (gMap != null) {

            ArrayList<PointModel> mapPosition = routesCV.get(position).getPoints();
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

            for (PointModel item : mapPosition) {
                points.add(new LatLng(item.getLatitude(),item.getLongitude()));
            }

            for (LatLng item : points) {
                gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(item));
            }

            zoomMapToLatLngBounds(holder.linearlayout, gMap, points);
        }

    }
```

Zoom method:

```
private void zoomMapToLatLngBounds(final LinearLayout layout,final GoogleMap mMap, final ArrayList<LatLng> bounds){

    LatLngBounds.Builder boundsBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

    for (int i=0; i<bounds.size(); i++) {
        boundsBuilder.include(bounds.get(i));
    }

    final LatLngBounds boundsfinal = boundsBuilder.build();

    final ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(boundsfinal, 25));
        }
    });
```

From logs public void onGlobalLayout() doesnt even execute. Do u know what might be the problem ? Tnx!

Comment: MapView is pretty expensive view, it should not be used inside RecyclerView. Instead generate location view images and use them in ImageView.

Comment: @Kristijian i am also implementing same thing can you please assist or help me to solve the issue of draw route .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a `OnMapLoadedCallback()` function to position the map. It works now!